# Green-Operator for Sturm-Liouville Differential equation compact on Sobolev space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $g$ be Green's Function for a Sturm-Liouville differential equation. Is the operator $G: H_{0}^{1}(0,1) \rightarrow H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$ defined by $(Gf)(x) := \int_{0}^{1} g(x,y)f(y) dy, \quad f \in H_{0}^{1}(0,1)\quad$ compact? It's clear that this would be true if we would define $G$ on $L^{2}(0,1)$, but it is not at all obvious to me in the case of $H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$. As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can have singular problems on $[0,1]$ where the Sturm-Liouville operator does not have discrete spectrum. In that case, the resolvent will not be compact.

Comment: Does that imply that $G$ is not compact in general? (The connection between the resolvent of the Sturm-Liouville operator $L$ and $G$ is not obvious to me). If so, is the statement true if we introduce some restrictions on $G$?

Comment: What does your operator $G$ do? How is it related to a Sturm-Liouville equation? I want to make sure we're on the same page.